# iCloud - UIDocument saveToUrl does not execute completion block

Tags: ios, icloud

I was testing with it the other day and it was working. Today, after calling this method, it never calls the completion block.

Is there a case where the completion block is not called? I remember Apple said that it's always called regardless of what happened.

Here's the code block:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
            // Get ubiquitous url
            NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                           URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
            NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:
                                         @"Documents"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

            // Create new CloudFile
            CloudFile *file = [[CloudFile alloc]initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
            file.data = data;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onDocumentStateChanged:) name:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification object:file];             

            dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^(void) {
                [file saveToURL:file.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                    NSLog(@"test");
                    if (success) {
                        [self sendEvent:ICLOUD_FILE_SAVE_SUCCESSFUL object:file];
                    } else {
                        [self sendEvent:ICLOUD_FILE_SAVE_FAILED];
                        NSLog(@"kaiCloud: Saving failed. (%@)",fileName);
                    }

                }];
            });

        });
```

EDIT: Note that I added NSLog(@"test") and I'm not seeing it getting logged.

Comment: does the save actually happen?

Comment: No. I don't see it in iCloud. Weird thing is I didn't change anything in the code, after I got back, it's not working anymore.

Comment: could you add logs to print `file`: before the inner `dispatch_async`, and before the file save (inside the inner async call)?

Comment: I'll log it next week. I'm not at work currently so I can't test.

But, looks like it doesn't work with specific devices for some reason. I tried it with 3 other devices and it works.

Still, I don't think that I shouldn't get any callback (I'll check it once I get back).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug anymore. That was very weird. Anyway, I got it working.

Comment: Is this unit test or code for application?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem (which is how I found your question).

The reason is simple. The test code is not waiting for the completion handler to be called and certainly not for it to finish executing.

Your test may work sometimes if they are long enough or happen to get stalled. But that's not reliable.

Use the WAIT macros provided and explained here and problem solved.

https://github.com/hfossli/AGAsyncTestHelper